# How to keep event bubbling

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, event-bubbling

I have two onclick events in jquery

```
$(document).on( 'click','#button', function(e){

})

$('*').on('click dblclick keypress scroll', function(e){
             if(e.target == $('#button').get(0) ){
                    return true;
             }
})
```

I want the first one to always execute and the second one to not execute if the aforementioned button was pressed.  The problem is it ALWAYS goes to the first one even though I bind it in the order above...and when it goes to the first it never goes to the second one which I need to execute.  I thought 'return true' keeps it bubbling but it just quits.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Couldn't you find a more accurate selector than `$('*')` ??? FYI, anything after a return statement will not be executed inside function scope. And be aware, delegate events are fired after direct bound events depending delegate target level

Comment: Im executing a screen saver where if anything is clicked it needs to do a settimeout at a later date to run the screen saver.  Therefore its needs to be any element clicked on the body.

Comment: The condition will always fail, `e.target` will ***never*** be the same as `$('#button')`

Comment: @adeneo good point! Leon, then delegate event to body element or document and avoid to bind hundred or more multiple exact same handlers as you are currently doing it

Comment: I don't really get it, if the button is clicked, what is supposed to happen exactly? Is the first event handler supposed to fire, but not the other one? If so the condition would be `if ( e.target.id != 'button' ) { do something for all the other elements }`

Comment: Sorry I updated it using get(0).  It hits in the Chrome debugger but still bypasses the first event handler

Comment: And what is `#button`? You're sure the page doesn't just reload

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/BCm35/

Comment: Changing '*' to 'body' still doesnt work

Comment: I found the problem.  The problem was indeed using '*' and not 'body'.  Also because of a known bug in jquery http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13353 I was using trigger('click') to execute the events. Since that didnt work I had to change it to triggerHandler but that didnt trigger the event for some reason.  It seems your suggestions were right but in all the combinations I was trying it didnt work.  Works now though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this condition at the start of the second function :

```
if(!$(e.target).closest('#button').length) {
    //Run your code
}
```

Comment: Doesnt returning false stop event propagation?

Comment: It will, try my edit instead. You don't need any return,

Comment: No I need to return from the second function because I dont want to run any code in that function.  I want to stop the second function in its tracks and go to the first one, but the event is not propagating and thats the problem.  Ive edited my equality in the above question

Comment: @Leon If the condition is `false`, no code in the function will run (since the code of the function is in the brackets). The condition say that if you click on `#button` or any of its childrens (actually i forgot the `!`) it will be false. And if there is no `return false` or `e.stopPropagation()`, the event will propagate...